# Smarty Date to use on TPL file

Tags: smarty

I have an announcement to make till some date, so I created a time variable as

```
$announcedate = strtotime('+6 day');
$now = "1382960040";
$smarty->assign('announcedate', $announcedate);
$smarty->assign('now', $now);
```

And included on tpl file as

```
{if $now > $announcedate}My Announcement{/if}
```

I want to be sure before using this and end the announcement specifically after 6th day.

is this the correct way? Or any other guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: This will work as you intend it.

However, I'd like to add a few suggestions:

[`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns an integer, and you compare it with a string. This doesn't necessary lead to problems in your use case, but should be improved anyway. A simple update like this changes that:

```
$announcedate = strtotime('+6 day');
$now = strtotime('now');
```

Your solution works for your specific task, but isn't very general. If you want to reuse this code for other purposes (other announcements for example) you'll most likely have to adapt the logic. For those reasons, and to keep as much logic away from your display layer smarty, I would check for the announcements only in my php code.

This would look something like this:

php (pseudo code, the idea is, function `myAnncouncements()` retrieves the announcements you need for a specific timeframe or whatever):

```
$smarty->assign('announcements', myAnncouncements());
```

smarty template:

```
{if isset($announcements)}
    {foreach $announcements as $item}
         // whatever is needed in here....
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: this is not working as intended. I want to end the announcement when 6th day is over. I think my greater if statement is not correct

Comment: If you want a specific end date, then just replace your `$announcedate` with a specific date (p.e. `$announcedate = strtotime('2013-11-30 12:00:00');` or something like this).

Comment: i tried it as $announcedate = strtotime('2013-10-30 12:00:00');
$now = strtotime('now');
$smarty->assign('announcedate', $announcedate);
$smarty->assign('now', $now); And on tpl file, {if $now > $announcedate}My Announcement{/if} ....... still its not working as intended. once the time is over then it will show, rather than within the time, please help

Comment: its working now i had to change less than in if function and its working fine now. thanks and by the way, I will implement your suggestion for function too, that's a pretty good idea and I accept your answer with vote up, thanks again.